# AWK Variable only gets stored in first cyle

Tags: variables, awk

I'm running a awk script as part of a bigger bash script. The awk part is supposed to add some parameters to each line of the input file which are generated by a script called script_1. It seems to me that the script script_1 does run for each line of the input file, but the results only seem to get stored in the variable 'max' during the first cycle.

```
cat ${location_array_code[$i]}.txt | gawk -v location="${location_array_code[$i]}" '
{max=""

 printf("%s %s 0 %s %s 0 10",$1, $2, $3, $4)                            > "script1.par"
 printf "%s %s %s %s %d \n", "A", "GET", location, "WT_h_6", 1          >> "script1.par"
 close("script1.par")

 script1_high="script1"
 script1_high | getline max
 printf "%s %s %s\n", $0, max }' > ${location_array_code[$i]}.txt
```

output of script_1 schould be digits such as: "20180203 1430  50"

the text file processed by awk called temp1.${location_array_code[$i]} consists of lines with a date time date time:

```
20180204 1432 20180204 2123
20180205 1023 20180205 1792
20180206 1732 20180206 2393
...
```

the resulting file now comes out like this:

```
20180204 1432 20180204 2123 20180203 1430  50
20180205 1023 20180205 1792
20180206 1732 20180206 2393
...
```

Why would the result of the script1 only be saved to variable max in the cycle?

Comment: I'm sure if you reduced that to the **Minimal** example that demonstrates your problem (as required to ask a question here, see [ask]) you'd figure out the solution yourself.

Comment: What does `script1` do? The way you're using it, you'll only read a single line from it. Is script1 designed to only output one line?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you don't `close(script1_high)`

Comment: @EdMorton, My bad, I have edited all the unnecessary code away now.

Comment: @Glennjackman, script1 is supposed to output a date, time and a number, in one line, but this should happen during every cycle and should be added to each corresponding line of the input file that awk is processing.

Comment: @glenn jackman That was it! Thanks a lot!